# Where can I find Rails application directory on AWS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my rails application on AWS via Elastic BeanStalk and now I want to open that directory. What would be it's path?

Answer (score 1):

Rails apps are deployed to `/var/app/current/`.